# I want to join two tables, in base model their ids are unknown in Laravel, I don't know how to fetch exact result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I'm trying to get data from `faculties` table. But I select `enrolments`.
Basically my idea is to show `course` that are enrolled with faculty name and sections

I tried all joins but nothing worked. I'm confused how to subjoin in Laravel Eloquent.

```php
$results = Enrollment::select(
               'students.rollnumber as student_rollnumber',
               'courses.name as course_name',
               'courses.course_code',
               'sections.name as section_name',
               'faculties.fname as faculty_fname',
               'faculties.lname as faculty_lname'
           )->join(
               'courses',
               'courses.id',
               'enrollments.course_id'
           )->join(
               'students',
               'students.id',
               'enrollments.student_id'
           )->join(
               'sections',
               'sections.id',
               'enrollments.section_id'
           )->join(
               'faculties',
               'faculties.section_id',
               'enrollments.section_id'
           )->join(
               'faculty_course_details',
               'faculties.id',
               'faculty_course_details.faculty_id'
           )->where('enrollments.student_id',9)
            ->get();
```

Error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'faculties.fname' in 'field list' (SQL: select `students`.`rollnumber` as `student_rollnumber`, `courses`.`name` as `course_name`, `courses`.`course_code`, `sections`.`name` as `section_name`, `faculties`.`fname` as `faculty_fname`, `faculties`.`lname` as `faculty_lname` from `enrollments` inner join `courses` on `courses`.`id` = `enrollments`.`course_id` inner join `students` on `students`.`id` = `enrollments`.`student_id` inner join `sections` on `sections`.`id` = `enrollments`.`section_id` where `enrollments`.`student_id` = 9)

Comment: are you really sure that `fname` exists in the `faculties` table? It would be best to add the database structure to your original message.

Comment: You should provide your database table and columns, so we can check if your query is right or not.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hFVmy-oWIdzj28vYvYDlcIh7s_CwfOKN/view?usp=sharing
here is my database

Comment: There is no guarantee that this external link will remain valid for future readers.... You must display this informations in your original message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made mistake while joining faculties and faculties_course_details. You are joining faculties with column section_id while there is no section_id column in faculties table

First join faculty_course_details on (faculty_course_details.section_id, enrollments.section_id) and then join faculties on (faculties.id, faculty_course_details.faculty_id) as below

```
$results = App\Enrollment::select(
           'students.rollnumber as student_rollnumber',
           'courses.name as course_name',
           'courses.course_code',
           'sections.name as section_name',
           'faculties.fname as faculty_fname',
           'faculties.lname as faculty_lname'
        )->join(
           'courses',
           'courses.id',
           'enrollments.course_id'
        )->join(
           'students',
           'students.id',
           'enrollments.student_id'
        )->join(
           'sections',
           'sections.id',
           'enrollments.section_id'
        )->join(
           'faculty_course_details',
           'faculty_course_details.section_id',
           'enrollments.section_id'
        )->join(
           'faculties',
           'faculties.id',
           'faculty_course_details.faculty_id'
        )
        ->where('enrollments.student_id',9)
        ->get();
```

You will get output as follows:

```
[
    {
       "student_rollnumber": "dummy_878wegy6",
       "course_name": "dummy_course",
       "course_code": "dummy_123",
       "section_name": "dummy_name",
       "faculty_fname": "John", 
       "faculty_lname": "Doe"
    }
]
```

Comment: Thank you so much this solved my problem brother...Great :)

Answer (score 0):

Because you have aliased faculties.fname with faculty_fname

Comment: here is database please https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hFVmy-oWIdzj28vYvYDlcIh7s_CwfOKN/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Check this query builder method..

```
$results = DB::table('enrollments)

         ->join('courses','courses.id','=','enrollments.course_id')
         ->join('students','students.id','=','enrollments.student_id')
         ->join('sections','sections.id','=','enrollments.section_id')
         ->join('faculties','faculties.section_id','=','enrollments.section_id')
         ->join('faculty_course_details','faculties.id','=','faculty_course_details.faculty_id')
         ->select('students.rollnumber as student_rollnumber','courses.name as course_name','courses.course_code','sections.name as section_name','faculties.fname as faculty_fname','faculties.lname as faculty_lname')
         ->where('enrollments.student_id','=',9)
         ->get();
```